# How to build exe with pyinstaller from python script which uses cvxpy and CBC?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, linear-programming, cvxpy, coin-or-cbc

I am trying to build exe from a python script to solve LP problem using cvxpy and CBC (through cylp) with pyinstaller. 
The code is like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.array([[2, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 2],
                  [0, 3, 1]])
    b = np.array([4, 8, 6])
    c = np.array([3, 4, 2])

    # Define and solve the problem.
    x = cp.Variable(3)
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(c.T @ x),
                      [A @ x <= b, x >= 0])
    prob.solve(solver=cp.CBC)
    print(f"solver: {prob.solver_stats.solver_name}")

    # Print result.
    print("The optimal value is", prob.value)
    print("A solution x is")
    print(x.value)
```

this works correctly with python interpreter

```
> python .\LP.py
solver: CBC
The optimal value is 16.0
A solution x is
[2. 1. 3.]
```

but exe made by pyinstaller throws error

```
> pyinstaller .\LP.spec
> .\dist\LP.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LP.py", line 15, in <module>
    prob.solve(solver=cp.CBC)
  File "cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 396, in solve
  File "cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 745, in _solve
  File "cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 500, in get_problem_data
  File "cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 651, in _construct_chain
  File "cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 576, in _find_candidate_solvers
cvxpy.error.SolverError: The solver CBC is not installed.
[18960] Failed to execute script LP
```

Is there a way to fix this?

I cannot avoid using CBC because what I actually want to do is to make an exe solving a Mixed-Integer Programming problem.

My environment:
     numpy: 1.19.1
     cvxpy: 1.1.4
     cylp: 0.91.0
     PyInstaller: 4.0
     Python: 3.7.9
     Platform: Windows 10 v1909 64bit

My spec file (made by `pyinstaller .\LP.py -F` and I modified `datas`):

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['LP.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\LP'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        ('C:\\Users\\aaa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\cylp\\*',
         '.\\cylp\\')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
          cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='LP',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same problem.  I've tried both of the following commands to build, with the same result:

```
    pyinstaller name_of_my_package.py
    pyinstaller --hidden-imports=cylp name_of_my_package.py
```

But I still get the same error.  Since I'm building mine with multiple files, I can just go into the dist/name_of_my_package/cylp/ directory and I can see that the cylp module folder exists, but it only has a cy subfolder in that directory.  When I delete dist/name_of_my_package/cylp/cy/ from the build and copy the contents of my cylp folder directly from my python virtual environment into dist/name_of_my_package/cylp/, my exe works.  But you can only do this if you aren't building with the --onefile flag.

I see the following folder structure when I'm done:

```
    dist/name_of_my_package/cylp/
    |--cpp/
       |--<a bunch of stuff in here>
    |--cy/
       |--<a bunch of stuff in here>
    |--py
       |--<a bunch of stuff in here>
    |--__init__.py
    |--VERSION
```

The original folder structure that pyinstaller built only looks like this:

```
    dist/name_of_my_package/cylp/
    |--cy/
       |--<a bunch of stuff in here>
```

It appears that pyinstaller knows to get the cylp package, but it doesn't copy all of the required pieces.  I'm not sure what the real answer is here, but this workaround works for me for now.  Hopefully, someone can point us to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the "--add-data" option or "Analysis/datas" first string is "relative to the location of the spec file."

[pyinstaller Read Doc Using Data File from a Module](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module)

I used the console line in Windows (double quotes and semicolon separator) to add the cpp entire directory and the VERSION file (do not need anything else).

> pyinstaller --add-data "cylp\cpp;cylp\cpp" --add-data "cylp\VERSION;cylp" LP.py

Add -F if you want the "onefile" build.

Since the first string path is relative, you first need to copy the entire cylp package-site folder from the original python directory into the directory of LP.py

PS: This is my first answer in Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller utilises temp folder (i.e xxxxx-MEIxxxxxx) to unpack all the dependencies with --onefile flag. you need to specify the path to pyinstaller using --paths and --add-data flags becoz it does not copy by its own. and also make sure of hidden libraries

for hidden library: `--paths /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cylp/.dylibs`

for linking the cylp library: `--add-data="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cylp:cylp"`

--add-data=`<Source:Destination">` 
macos